# Storyboard - connect distant scenes

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I've got a bunch of controllers on my storyboard but I'm struggling to connect two scenes that are far apart graphically.

You can't seem to do it when zoomed out and when you're zoomed in you can't see both scenes on the storyboard.

Suggestions?

==== UPDATE ====

Holding the arrow at the edge of the screen did it but wasn't easy finding that magic boundary initially. 
Ticked as correct answer although not quite sure what was meant by the = sign shortcut.

The doc outline is handy. For those wanting to use it - there's a little arrow button bottom left of the storyboard. Or use Editor > Show Document Outline (or Reveal in Document Outline).

Comment: Did my answer help? If so please accept it.  The easiest way to do it will be my second half where you use the outline view to connect the two view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hit = sign and then ctrl drag from one controller to other it should work.  You hold the end of the arrow at edge of screen and it should scroll the screen for you.  Oh also you can use the document outline(the area next to navigator that has the arrow pointing left that opens and closes it) and ctrl drag from one controller to the other.